# Showing same dfp ads in a single page web application

Tags: javascript, ads, single-page-application, google-dfp

I have a single page web application which contains dfp ads. I have two dfp adunits that Iam firing and they are placed in between the content which is a list of articles for a particular category.

When I click on another category,it just loads articles for different category(doesnt change the url in address bar) and triggers the same ads. So this is like triggering the ads on the same page.

The ads dont show up the second time and this is because you cant use the same adunits on the same page.

Since I cannot use the refresh function provided by dfp since my DOM is reconstructed everytime, is there any way I can do this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery take a look at the [plugin](https://github.com/coop182/jquery.dfp.js) I made which wraps DFP and allows you to use it quite easily within single page apps.

This is a demo using turbolinks which will be similar to your single page app:

http://coop182.github.io/jquery.dfp.js/dfptests/demo1.html

Any more questions just let me know.

Edit: here is another Single page example - http://coop182.github.io/jquery.dfp.js/dfptests/spa.html

Comment: How is the above demo a single page app.?. Clicking on the link takes you to another page.
Check out the modified version of the above demo. http://app.genwi.com/resources/44132/misc/ad_single_page.html. 




When you click on refresh here; it tries to create the same ad; but fails to serve an ad.

Comment: The initial demo is definitely a single page app... turbolinks handles the click and pushes the url change to the browser... so even though it looks like it is changing pages it is not. Anyway... I have added another demo that should provide a better example... the one you made is not working because you are changing the id and emptying the div...

Comment: Thanks for the demo. I still have one confusion. When I remove enableSingleRequest:false from the demo, it doesn't trigger new ads. Can you tell me why enableSingleRequest is used?

Comment: DFP uses the enableSingleRequest option to get all the ads for the current page at once... when using this option its not possible to then fetch further ads for the same page... my plugin sets enableSingleRequest to true by default because for most situations it is more efficient but for single page apps where you are generating and fetching new ads on the same page you will always need to set enableSingleRequest to false.

Comment: Just one more confusion; you said my above demo doesnt work because Iam emptying the div and changing the id. Is that a limitation of the googletag implementation itself and we cannot use it this way?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure... I have a feeling its the way DFP works internally... but it could be fixable in my plugin code... I just haven't investigated it further as there are easy work arounds.

Comment: @MattCooper can I use this library in my rails app(with turbolinks) to serve adsense ads via dfp. Is it policy complaint or safe to use?

Comment: @StarWars yes you can use it in that way without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

There are few takeaways from this question.
The dfp plugin as well as normal googletag implementation should work for a single page app, just that two requirements should be fulfilled

1. enableSingleRequest should NOT be set to true. In case of dfp plugin by Matt you should pass enableSingleRequest:false so that he doesn't set it to true. 
   This is because if you set it to true you cant raise more request on the same page to fetch ads. Also enableSingleRequest(false) also fails.
2. When you are triggering ads dynamically i.e without reloading page; make sure to start with fresh containers where the ads will be placed. The exact reason for this is still not confirmed but seems like that is the way googletag works internally.

Please add if you have any further comments.

Answer (score 0):

Do it the hard way:

```
function myGoogleTagLoaderFn(callback) {
    // reset googletag lib
    window.googletag = null;

    // we're using requirejs, so we have to do this as well
    window.requirejs.undef('http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js');

    myRequireOr$getScriptFn('http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js', function success() { callback(); });
}
```

Don't worry about loading the library on every page load, this is the same as in a non-singlepage site, and the lib sends reasonable cache headers. The downside of course is that the script gets re-evaluated everytime. The upside is you can use singleRequest mode this way.